# Dúvida com os If statements em R

Tags: r, if

Nesse código eu estou querendo registrar a quantidade de valores de `z` tais que `-1 < z < 1` dentro de `x`, e `z < -1` ou `z > 1` em `w`. Ele roda o `rnorm(100)`(ou seja, cria 100 observações de uma variável aleatória normal padrão) e registra os seus números no `z`, porém só um número é contabilizado em `w` ou `x` e depois acusa erro no else e nas chaves. Gostaria de entender o porquê do `R` estar acusando erro nas chaves e no else e o que eu fiz errado, e se eu posso por escrever algo como `if(-1<z<1)` pra deixar mais fácil.

```
# x = números de -1 a 1 // w = números maiores que 1 e menores que -1
x<-0
w<-0
z <- rnorm(100)
if(-1 >= z | z >= 1){
  w<-w + 1
} else{
  x <- x + 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Gostaria de entender o porquê do R estar acusando erro nas chaves e no else

Ao fazer uma estrutura condicional com `if` e `else`, não é necessário colocar o teste lógico para o `else`. Isto torna o teste redundante. Afinal, se a condição do `if` não é satisfeita, a única coisa que pode ocorrer é a sua negação, pelo princípio do terceiro excluído.

Outro detalhe a se perceber é que `z` possui 100 elementos. É necessário testar se cada um deles está no intervalo entre -1 e 1. Para fazer isso individualmente, o melhor a se fazer é construir um `for`, que é um laço de repetição. No `for` abaixo, eu iniciarei minha contagem em 1 e irei até o último elemento de `z`, denotado por `length(z)`:

```
set.seed(1234) # comando para garantir que vamos gerar os mesmos valores com rnorm
for (j in 1:length(z)){
  if(-1 >= z[j] | z[j] >= 1){
    w <- w + 1
  } else {
    x <- x + 1
  }
}
x
[1] 66
w
[1] 34
```

Agora sim temos o resultado desejado.

Uma outra maneira de fazer isso, que considero mais elegante, não utiliza o `if`. Veja o que acontece quando realizamos testes lógicos com um vetor no `R`:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
a >= 4
[1] FALSE FALSE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Ele retorna `FALSE` ou `TRUE` para cada posição do vetor original. Internamente, o `R` trata `FALSE` como o valor `0` e `TRUE` como valor `1`. Assim, se eu somar a quantidade de `TRUE` de um vetor, eu consigo saber quantas das suas posições satisfazem a regra que me interessa. No caso acima, basta fazer

```
sum(a >= 4)
[1] 2
```

e temos o resultado desejado. Para o teu exemplo, com o vetor `z`, bastaria fazer algo como

```
sum(!(z < -1 | z > 1))
[1] 66
sum(z < -1 | z > 1)
[1] 34
```

e o mesmo resultado é obtido. Note que `!` é o comando do `R` para achar a negação (ou o complementar) de `(z < -1 | z > 1)`.